# VSTS .Net Core 2.0 rename published zip file

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have a .net core 2.0 web project, VSTS build definition's publish task is configured with "zip published projects" settings and another task to copy the zip file to s3 bucket. Zip file is always generating with ***name of the project***.zip, is it possible to specify our own name for the file?

Comment: Or you can use ccnet build to manual or auto deployment and it every time build with you version, It might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported with .NET Core Publish task, but you can do it with PowerShell through PowerShell task.

[Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Added inline PS script to rename the file. Rename-Item $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Web.zip NewFileName.zip